# Migrate users to Azure AD B2C from multiple sources

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are looking to migrate users from an existing system into Azure AD B2C and are planning on following the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration. As we hash our user's passwords, we will need to use the seamless migration flow.

This is fine where you have user accounts to be migrated from a single external source. However, currently we have several existing websites, which each have their own authentication process that we want to move to all being authenticated from a single B2C.

Going through the migration process for a single website is fine, as we would import (eg : 1000) users for this website. However, if we are to then migrate users from a second website we have, we would then import (eg: 800) users, where a subset of these users (eg: 300) would have already been imported from the first migration.

Because the two sites are currently completely separate, a user with an account in both might currently be using the same password for both sites, or different passwords for both sites. We can't assume either. There is likely to be some users that fall into each category.

We will only want to create a single account for them in B2C with a randomised password. When they try to log into the first migrated site, if they have entered the correct password, they will trigger the process to overwrite the random password and mark their account as migrated.

However, if they then try to login to the second website, what now? Do they need to go through the migration process again? Or can we treat their account as already migrated?

Can we run multiple migration processes in parallel with one another without issue? Would we need a unique `extension_requiresMigration` flag for each process?

Would we want to only run each migration process for a limited time? Some of our users only login very infrequently (eg: once a year). So if we were to end the migration process, any users that logged in for the first time after this would be forced to reset their password using the forgot password process instead?

I appreciate that that is a lot of questions, but has anyone come across this situation before? Or can you recommend a different approach to use?

Comment: How many websites?

Comment: I believe it's 2. But could possibly be more. Would this make a difference?

Comment: Essentially you could use the user migration example, but call both legacy IdPs sequentially. And if one works, the user is migrated and essentially uses the password at time of migration for both sites on subsequent logins. If there are many sites, then this just gets clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

Why not export all users so that you can combine the list, then import the list of users without duplicates? Then initiate a password reset for each user? May be the easiest way rather than going down the custom policy route.

Comment: I'm not sure if we want to go down to route of forcing all users to update their passwords. We would like the transition to be seamless for as many users as possible.

Comment: You could do it with a custom policy and some api calls I think. However, they are complex and a pain in the ass. I’ve been working on one for the last 2 weeks, and still needs a lot of work. Trying to understand them is very hard in my view, once you have been working with them for a bit they become easier. I’ve been looking into custom policies for us for about 6 months now, still struggling to grasp them